# Physical interpretation for the curl of a field

Tags: calculus

I was supposed to compute the curl of a field for a fairly simple assignment and got the following :

$$\nabla \times F = (0,0,y-e^{x+y}) \text{ ; } (x,y) \in [0,1]\times [0,1]$$

However, I'm unable to appreciate the meaning of this and I hate doing things like a machine. I tried a few different online sources, but I still don't know how to interpret my result.

Can someone explain, in a natural manner, what implications does my result have ?

Comment: It is a measure of the rotation of vector field $F$. Think (loosely) of a tiny sphere 'floating' in the vector field, whose surface moves at the same speed as the field. The sphere will have some motion and rotation. The curl measures this rotation.

Comment: [This](http://betterexplained.com/articles/vector-calculus-understanding-circulation-and-curl/) page offers some intuition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another interpretation, for vector fields in the plane (which it sounds like is the case for your problem. The situation is a bit more complex in full 3 dimensions).

Let's say that you draw a small closed loop in the plane. Start at one point of the loop, and travel around it. Imagine that the vector field is now a gradient field of a height function $z(x,y)$ of a landscape over the plane: i.e. the vector field tells you in which direction the ground slopes, and at what angle. As you travel around the loop, your height in changing. Once you end up back at the point you started, what is your height relative to your starting point?

On an ordinary landscape e.g. a mountain, you end up at exactly the same height you started. But if you are, say, in a parking garage, you might end up higher or lower than where you started, even though you are at the same $(x,y)$ position in the plane.

Now imagine you take your loop and shrink it smaller and smaller and around some point $(x,y)$ in the plane. The difference in starting and ending height will depend on 1) how many times you *wind* around the point (twice around the parking garage takes you up two levels, negative once around takes you down a level) and 2) the curl of the vector field at $(x,y)$. Curl zero corresponds to the mountain case, where you end up back where you started (and indeed, if $\nabla \times v =0$, this is exactly the integrability condition needed to guarantee that $v = \nabla \phi$ for some potential $\phi$. This is why all force fields arising from potentials in physics are curl-free, i.e. "conservative": if you go around a closed path the force must have done no net work and your potential at the end is equal to your potential at the start.)

Comment: Really nice and clarifying andswer, thank you for your effort !

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I cant comment, because my reputation is not big enough, so I will just answer...

Imagine you throw a ball inside the vector field. This ball starts to move alonge the vectors and the curl of a vectorfield is a measure of how much the ball is rotating.
The curl gives you the axis around which the ball rotates, its direction gives you the direction of the orientation (clockwise/counterclockwise) and its length the speed of the rotation.

This is some curde model to give you some imagination about the curl...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear, natural presentation ! (+1) .